# Unable to mount an sdcard

Tags: mount, sd-card, fat

I wanted to mount an sdcard. Upon inserting the dmesg logs gives me this:

```
[Thu Oct 25 10:59:44 2018] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] 30318592 512-byte logical blocks: (15.5 GB/14.5 GiB)
[Thu Oct 25 10:59:44 2018]  sdb: sdb1
```

Looks fine, but when I want to mount it, it fails, using command `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdcard`, this is the dmesg output:

```
[Thu Oct 25 10:59:55 2018] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0x00038a03)
[Thu Oct 25 10:59:55 2018] FAT-fs (sdb1): Filesystem has been set read-only
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong? I don't want to format the card as I would lose all the data.

Comment: Not sure if that applies here, with openSUSE I had to install `exfat-utils` to be able to mount FAT.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Linux kernel source at `<source code root>/fs/fat/fatent.c` reveals that the message might be somewhat poorly worded: it actually means the FAT entry being accessed is not passing a validity check.

You might want to unmount the card and then run `fsck.fat -n /dev/sdb1` to evaluate the health of the filesystem on the card, and then perhaps run `fsck.fat -aw /dev/sdb1` to attempt to fix it.

Before attempting to fix the filesystem, if the files in it are important, you might want to make and image file of the contents of the card: `dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/some/place/with/plenty/of/space/sdcard.img bs=16k`

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that it might be due to the SD card's locking mechanism, but I Googled around a bit, and it sounds like this is the message you get when Linux tries to read corrupted data from a FAT partition.  I would try an fsck.  If that doesn't fix it, then you might not have a choice but to reformat.  It might still be possible to recover some data, though, if the SD card is indeed at least mounting read-only.